# Ruby: Any consequences with using multiple return..if statements?

Tags: ruby

I have a method that returns a value based on the truthiness of other method calls. My initial thought was to use a series of `return..if` statements, but I'm thinking a `case` statement might be more appropriate. Both produce the desired results.

Here's an example of each:

```
def triangle(side1, side2, side3)
  sides = [side1, side2, side3]
  max = sides.max
  min = sides.min

  return :invalid if !valid_triangle?(sides, max, min)
  return :equilateral if equilateral?(sides, max)
  return :isosceles if isosceles?(sides, max, min)
  return :scalene if scalene?(sides)
end
```

Or...

```
def triangle(side1, side2, side3)
  sides = [side1, side2, side3]
  max = sides.max
  min = sides.min

  case
  when !valid_triangle?(sides, max, min) then :invalid
  when equilateral?(sides, max) then :equilateral
  when isosceles?(sides, max, min) then :isosceles
  when scalene?(sides) then :scalene
  end
end
```

Are there any consequences of using either approach?
If so, how could it be avoided?

EDIT: Based on the comments, I feel like my question has been answered. Avoiding a series of `return..if` statements would provide better-debugging efficiency with `Object#tap`, and avoiding an empty `case` statement would pass Rubocop's [Style/EmptyCaseCondition](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/cops_style.html#styleemptycasecondition) cop. The selected answer provides a viable solution that satisfies both points.

Comment: One consideration is that when debugging you could modify the case statement's `end` to `end.tap { |rv| puts "ret value by #{__method__} = #{rv}"`, but in #1 four such expressions would be required (e.g., `(puts :scalene returned by #{__method__}"; return :scalene) if scalene?(sides)`. In general I suggest that you employ a premature `return` statements only when there is no easy way to avoid an explicit `return` statement. This is a topic that has been debated to death. See, for example, [this article](https://medium.com/better-programming/are-early-returns-any-good-eed4b4d03866).

Comment: This is really a general question about practice in any language: when, if ever, should there be an *early return* from a method or function? Try Googling, 'programming practice "early return"'.

Comment: Use Ruby's implicit return with an if statement at the end of the method like `if valid_triangle?(); if equilateral?(); :equilateral; elsif isosceles?(); :isosceles; elsif scalene?(); :scalene; end; else; :invalid; end` (but I have to say, ask ten developers the same question and you'll get 20 answers, which is why I voted to close this question as opinion-based)

Comment: I appreciate the comments. I think Cary's point on debugging efficiency is enough reason to avoid a series of `return..if` statements in favor of `case` statements. This answers my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an extended comment. No upvotes, please (downvotes OK).

I would be inclined to write this as follows.

```
def triangle(side1, side2, side3) 
  if valid_triangle?(side1, side2, side3)
    triangle_type(side1, side2, side3)
  else
    :invalid
  end     
end
```

```
def triangle_type(*sides)
  case nbr_equal_sides(sides)
  when 3
    :equilateral
  when 2
    :isosceles
  else
    :scalene
  end
end
```

```
def valid_triangle?(*sides)
  sides.sum > 2 * sides.max
end
```

```
def nbr_equal_sides(sides)
  4 - sides.uniq.size
end
```

Line segments of lengths `n1`, `n2`, `n3` can form a triangle if and only if the following three inequalities hold:

```
n1 + n2 > n3
n1 + n3 > n2
n2 + n3 > n1
```

which can be written:

```
tot > 2 * n3
tot > 2 * n2
tot > 2 * n1
```

where

```
tot = n1 + n2 + n3
```

which is the same as:

```
tot > 2 * [n1,n2,n3].max
```

Those not philosophically opposed to early returns could use a *guard clause* in `triangle`:

```
def triangle(side1, side2, side3) 
  return :invalid unless valid_triangle?(side1, side2, side3)
  triangle_type(side1, side2, side3)
end
```

The [Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide) (search "guard clause") and [Robocop](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/0.86/cops_style.html#styleguardclause) advocate the use of guard clauses.